# How can you put span tag inside anchor tag in Html.ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can anybody tell me how do I put span tag inside anchor tag?

This doesn't work:

```
@Html.ActionLink("<span>Home</span>", "Home", "Home",new { @class = "active" })
```

I get Html encoded output if I do like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Url.Action` insted of `Html.ActionLink`. Try this

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Home","Home")" class="active">
     <span>Home</span>
 </a>
```

Comment: Great you guys came to the rescue!

Answer (score 1):

Do the following :

```
<a class="active" 
    href="@Url.Action("YourAction", new { controller = "YourController"})">
    <span>content comes here</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Great you guys came to the rescue!